# Ef core LazyLoading - Access nested navigation property of type collection threw DetachedLazyLoadingWarning error

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, asp.net-core, .net-core

I tried to access the GradeInfo property of the student's latest grade using ef core 2.1

**I listed the models at the end of the question**

```
var students = applicationDbContext.Students.Where(s => s.Id ==2)
    .Select(student => new { 
        LatestGrade = student.Grades.OrderBy(g => g.Date).FirstOrDefault(),
        Id = student.Id
        }).ToList();
```

In addition I use lazy loading proxies (from Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Proxies) in startup.cs

```
services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options => 
    options.UseLazyLoadingProxies()
           .UseSqlServer(connectionString));
```

The error which is thrown is:

> "Error generated for warning Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.DetachedLazyLoadingWarning: An attempt was made to lazy-load navigation property 'Info' on detached entity of type 'GradeProxy'. Lazy-Loading is not supported for detached entities or entities that are loaded with 'AsNoTracking()'."

In addition, i want to state that I tried to add Inculde to the sudents's dbset as described in the following code, but the problem did not resolved.

```
var student = applicationDbContext.Students.Include( s => s.Grades )
                .ThenInclude( grade => grade.Info).Where(...).Select(...)
```

---

***models***

```
class Student{
   public int Id { get; set;}
   public virtual ICollection<Grade> Grades { get; set;}

   ...
}

class Grade {
   public virtual GrandeInfo Info { get; set;}
   public DateTime Date { get; set;}
}

class GrandeInfo {
  public int Id { get; set;}
  public int Score { get; set;}
}
```

Comment: Is there any demo to reproduce your issue? I made a test with Asp.Net Core 2.2, and I fail to reproduce your issue.

Comment: I wish to clarify, that the ToList() succeed, and the soldiers do have data as Id and the Grade's date, but instead of data in the GradeInfo property there is an exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this issue, it is caused by that if you change the query so that it no longer returns instances of the entity type that the query began with, then the include operators are ignored. You could refer [Ignored includes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data#ignored-includes)
.

And, currently, it is not supported to query the navigation property by `Include`, refer [Are .Include/.ThenInclude supposed to work with Select in RC1-final? #4641](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/4641).

For a workaround, you need to query all the columns in the db and then query the expected type at client side.

```
var students = _context.Students
                    .Where(s => s.Id == 2)
                    .ToList()
                    .Select(student => new
                    {
                        LatestGrade = student.Grades.OrderBy(g => g.Date).FirstOrDefault(),
                        Id = student.Id
                    })
                    .ToList();
```